# SQL Server 2016 - Stuff/XML Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this basic query, bringing back configuration information. Each `MatrixCellID` is an individual ticket, and each can have multiple `StatisticalGroupCodes` and `StatisicalGroupDescriptions`. Currently each `MatrixCellID` appears multiple times because of its multiple `StatisicalGroupCodes`. I would like the Code and Description columns to show all in one column, comma separated.

This is my query:

```
select
  cmc.MatrixSheetId,
  CMS.MatrixSheetName,
  cmc.MatrixCellId,
  CMC.Price,
  CMC.PriceListId,
  CPL.PriceListName,
  CPT.Description as PriceTable,
  case when CMC.Code <> '' then cmc.code else 'EMPTY' end AS TicketCode,
  case when CMC.Name <> '' then cmc.name else 'EMPTY' END AS TicketName,
  case when CMC.Description <> '' then cmc.description else 'EMPTY' END AS TicketDescription,
  case when CMC.Description2 <> '' then cmc.description2 else 'EMPTY' end  AS AdditionalTicketDescription,
  CASE WHEN CMCI.AccountMandatory = 1 THEN 'YES' else 'NO' end AS AccountMandatory,
  CASE WHEN CDC.Description IS NULL THEN 'NONE' ELSE CDC.Description END  AS AccountCategory,
  CDT.DocTemplateName AS PrintTemplate,
  CTP.Description as TaxPackage,
  CT.TaxName,
  CASE when CMC.PriceType = 0 then 'Fixed' else 'Variable' end as PriceType,
  CCC.CostCenterDescription,
  CCC.CostCenterCode,
  CCC.CostCenterAK,
  CSG.StatisticalGroupCode,
  CSG.StatisticalGroupDescription
from
 CNF_MatrixCell CMC
 inner join CNF_MatrixSheet CMS on CMC.MatrixSheetId = CMS.MatrixSheetId
 inner join CNF_PriceList CPL on CMC.PriceListId = CPL.PriceListId
 INNER JOIN CNF_MatrixCellInfo CMCI on CMC.MatrixCellId = CMCI.MatrixCellId
 left join CNF_DmgCategory CDC on CMCI.AccountDmgCatId = CDC.DmgCategoryId
 left join CNF_DocTemplate CDT on CMC.DocTemplateId = CDT.DocTemplateId
 LEFT join CNF_TaxPackage CTP on CMC.TaxPackageId = CTP.TaxPackageId
 LEFT join CNF_Tax2Package CT2P on CTP.TaxPackageId = CT2P.TaxPackageId
 LEFT JOIN CNF_Tax CT on CT2P.TaxId = CT.TaxId
 LEFT JOIN CNF_CostCenter_Validity CCCV on CMC.MatrixCellId = cccv.MatrixCellId
 LEFT JOIN CNF_CostCenter CCC on CCCV.CostCenterId = CCC.CostCenterId
 inner join CNF_PriceTable CPT on CMC.PriceTableId = CPT.PriceTableId
 LEFT JOIN CNF_StatisticalGroupValidity CSGV on CMC.MatrixCellId = CSGV.MatrixCellId
 LEFT JOIN CNF_StatisticalGroup CSG on CSGV.StatisticalGroupId = CSG.StatisticalGroupId
WHERE CMC.Enabled = 1
  AND CCC.Enabled = 1
  AND CPT.Enabled = 1
  AND CMS.Enabled = 1
ORDER BY
  CMS.MatrixSheetId,
  CMC.MatrixCellId,
  CMC.Code
```

I have tried to use Stuff and XML Path, but cannot get it work correctly with my joins.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without seeing what you tried and an example of expected results, I think you should try a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list for the comma-separated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
select
    cmc.MatrixSheetId,
    CMS.MatrixSheetName,
    cmc.MatrixCellId,
    CMC.Price,
    CMC.PriceListId,
    CPL.PriceListName,
    CPT.Description as PriceTable,
    case when CMC.Code <> '' then cmc.code else 'EMPTY' end AS TicketCode,
    case when CMC.Name <> '' then cmc.name else 'EMPTY' END AS TicketName,
    case when CMC.Description <> '' then cmc.description else 'EMPTY' END AS TicketDescription,
    case when CMC.Description2 <> '' then cmc.description2 else 'EMPTY' end  AS AdditionalTicketDescription,
    CASE WHEN CMCI.AccountMandatory = 1 THEN 'YES' else 'NO' end AS AccountMandatory,
    CASE WHEN CDC.Description IS NULL THEN 'NONE' ELSE CDC.Description END  AS AccountCategory,
    CDT.DocTemplateName AS PrintTemplate,
    CTP.Description as TaxPackage,
    CT.TaxName,
    CASE when CMC.PriceType = 0 then 'Fixed' else 'Variable' end as PriceType,
    CCC.CostCenterDescription,
    CCC.CostCenterCode,
    CCC.CostCenterAK,
    STUFF(StatGrpCode.StatGroupCodes,1,1,'') StatGroupCodes,
    STUFF(StatGrpCodeDesc.StatGroupDescription,1,1,'') StatGroupDescription
from
    CNF_MatrixCell CMC 
    inner join  CNF_MatrixSheet CMS on CMC.MatrixSheetId = CMS.MatrixSheetId
    inner join  CNF_PriceList CPL on CMC.PriceListId = CPL.PriceListId
    INNER JOIN  CNF_MatrixCellInfo CMCI on CMC.MatrixCellId = CMCI.MatrixCellId
    left join   CNF_DmgCategory CDC on CMCI.AccountDmgCatId = CDC.DmgCategoryId
    left join   CNF_DocTemplate CDT on CMC.DocTemplateId = CDT.DocTemplateId
    LEFT join   CNF_TaxPackage CTP on CMC.TaxPackageId = CTP.TaxPackageId
    LEFT join   CNF_Tax2Package CT2P on CTP.TaxPackageId = CT2P.TaxPackageId
    LEFT JOIN   CNF_Tax CT on CT2P.TaxId = CT.TaxId
    LEFT JOIN   CNF_CostCenter_Validity CCCV on CMC.MatrixCellId = cccv.MatrixCellId
    LEFT JOIN   CNF_CostCenter CCC on CCCV.CostCenterId = CCC.CostCenterId
    inner join  CNF_PriceTable CPT on CMC.PriceTableId = CPT.PriceTableId
    LEFT JOIN   CNF_StatisticalGroupValidity CSGV on CMC.MatrixCellId = CSGV.MatrixCellId
    OUTER APPLY 
        ( SELECT ', ' + CSG.StatisticalGroupCode  
            FROM CNF_StatisticalGroup CSG 
            WHERE CSGV.StatisticalGroupId = CSG.StatisticalGroupId FOR XML PATH('') ) StatGrpCode (StatGroupCodes)
    OUTER APPLY 
        ( SELECT ', ' + CSG.StatisticalGroupDescription 
            FROM CNF_StatisticalGroup CSG 
            WHERE CSGV.StatisticalGroupId = CSG.StatisticalGroupId FOR XML PATH('') ) StatGrpCodeDesc (StatGroupDescription)
WHERE CMC.Enabled = 1
    AND CCC.Enabled = 1
    AND CPT.Enabled = 1
    AND CMS.Enabled = 1

ORDER BY
    CMS.MatrixSheetId,
    CMC.MatrixCellId,
    CMC.Code
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough! I'm trying to work out how to copy my results in here, then I will message again

Comment: What I would like to see is one row per Matrix Cell ID, with the Codes in one column, and the Descriptions in another, separated by comma for example:    MatrixCellID 3181; StatGroupCodes Event,TOL,PUBEV; StatGroupDescription All Events,Tower of London, Public Events.             Right now I get 3 rows for this information. Thanks